# Disable hover with knockout condition

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js, hover, bind

I have a button which looks like this:

```html
<button data-bind="enable: valid, css:{'btn-primary': valid() === true}">
```

I would like to disable with the same condition `valid() === true`. In essence I want to add `pointer-events: none` when my function is equal to `true` using knockout bindings.

Comment: Your last sentence doesn't make much sense to me, specifically in context of your question title (which mentions "hover" whereas your question doesn't). Perhaps a language issue? Please clarify your post, show us a small repro, include what you've tried and researched so far.

Comment: Totally language issue, English is not my main language. About my question, I want to add   "pointer-events: none",  when my function is equal with "true"using knockout bind.

Comment: you can create an new class .pointerevent{ pointer-events: none; } and you can add this class with your existing condition css:{'btn-primary pointerevent': valid() === true}

Comment: @Gra I've taken the liberty of adding your clarification to the post. Note that you could've also done that by clicking "edit" below the question. That would also bump your question a bit, giving it some renewed attention. In any case, with your clarification the question became clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title says "disable hover", but the question (slipstreamed from earlier PO comments) mentions wanting to add a `pointer-events` css value. I'll assume the latter to be the final instruction.

The most sane way to do so would be to have a class that is enabled/disabled, as per @SivanrajM's comment. For example:

```js
ko.applyBindings({ valid: ko.observable(true) });

// For demo purposes:
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("clicked!");
});
```

```css
.btn-primary { text-transform: uppercase; }
.no-ptr-evts { pointer-events: none; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="enable: valid,
                   css: { 'btn-primary': valid,
                          'no-ptr-evts': valid }">
  (try to) click me
</button>
<hr>
<label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: valid"> `valid`</label>
```

It's unclear to me why you would want (*as per your question*) to disable pointer events when `valid() === true`, but hey: that's up to you!

Note that I've reduced `valid() === true` to just `valid`, which is equivalent.

By the way, if you want to skip creating a seperate class and do the knockout-analogy of an inline style, use [the `style` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html):

```js
ko.applyBindings({ valid: ko.observable(true) });

// For demo purposes:
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("clicked!");
});
```

```css
.btn-primary { text-transform: uppercase; }
.no-ptr-evts { pointer-events: none; color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<button data-bind="enable: valid,
                   css: { 'btn-primary': valid },
                   style: { 'pointer-events': valid() ? 'none' : 'auto' }">
  (try to) click me
</button>
<hr>
<label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: valid"> `valid`</label>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help not just for the issue because you help me with the code guide. I was trying to do it because,that is the condition for disable the button but it was confusing for the user when the hover was active in a disable button.